# Error adding Identity Scaffolding to a default program that was created using individual login

Tags: frameworks, entity

I create a template .NET 7.0 web mvc template, then add scaffolding to edit the appearance of the login page by introducing  the entity scaffolding and the generic ap does not rub anymore.  I do not make any programmatic changes at all

being able to edit the login html

Comment: Don't write normal sentences in all upper-case, not even titles. That's considered shouting, and it's very rude to shout at the people you want to help you.